# Calculating standard deviation using stats

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following data set,

```
1.54    23.66
1.75    26.25
1.92    30.20
2.08    34.46
2.44    42.08
2.78    46.81
3.03    51.10
3.70    52.99
4.17    56.15
4.76    59.34
```

To calculate the Standard Deviation 
(SD) of the first two points, I use,

```
stats "data.dat" u 2 every ::0::1
```

However, this is giving me the wrong 
SD = 1.2950 (The correct being 1.83)

```
* FILE: 
  Records:      2
  Out of range: 0
  Invalid:      0
  Blank:        0
  Data Blocks:  1

* COLUMN: 
  Mean:         24.9550
  Std Dev:       1.2950
  Sum:          49.9100
  Sum Sq.:    1248.8581

  Minimum:      23.6600 [0]
  Maximum:      26.2500 [1]
  Quartile:     23.6600 
  Median:       24.9550 
  Quartile:     26.2500 0
```

So what am I doing wrong? TIA.

Comment: It seems Gnuplot is normalizing the Standard dev with N, that is, it is producing the square root of the second moment of the sample about its mean. The value of `1.8314` is when you normalize by N-1

Comment: As far as I understand gnuplot has it right--the standard deviation of two points is half the difference between them (and this is usually not a very meaningful quantity).

Comment: @andyras, the small sample is one factor. Actually both values of 1.2950 and 1.8314 are correct. The difference is that OP has termed the correct value to be 1.8314 which is essentially the unbiased statistical estimator. That is, while calculating STDEV normalization is done by N-1 where N is the sample size. However, it seems that default Gnuplot behaviour is to normalize by N, which in statistical sense would be called a biased estimator.

Comment: Thanks Zahaib for the explanation. @Andyras, thanks for your gnuplot definition of SD.

Comment: If I understand correctly (please correct me if I'm wrong!), the difference between normalizing by N and by N-1 is related to the difference between "sample" and "population". If you have a sample, that is other values exist but you don't know them or take them into account, then the normalization should be done by N-1. If you have a population, that is you are considering all the values that exist, then you should normalize by N. In any case, you can correct the value multiplying by N/(N-1).

Comment: @Miguel, yes thats my understanding as well and indeed you can convert one to the other as outlined by you.

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar I just realized it should actually be sqrt(N/(N-1))

Comment: @Miguel Oh yes thats correct, just checked as well. BTW someone should  perhaps add an answer to the question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `1.83` that you mention as correct is obtained when Standard Deviation is normalized by `sqrt(N-1)` where `N` is the sample size. This is done to prevent the bias in the estimation. That is, calculating the Standard Deviation using a randomly drawn sample from the population such that its expected value equals the true value.

Gnuplot `stats` treats the provided data set as the population and hence normalizes by `sqrt(N)`. The value of `1.29` is therefore also correct, you may also convert values from one to the other.

For example: to convert `1.29` to `1.83` multiply by `sqrt(N/N-1)`

For a more complete discussion follow this Wikipedia link:

[Unbiased estimation of Standard Deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation)

Comment: Thanks to you all once again